# nodejs mongodb query issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb

index.js

```
console.log(friender_database.checkIsExist(event.source.userId));`
```

database.js

```
function checkIsExist(user_Id) {
  var result = false;
     MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/friender_database", function(err,db){
      db.collection('users_list',function(err,collection){
       collection.find({}).toArray(function(err,items){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log("We found "+items.length+" results!");            
            result = true;
        });
      });
      db.close(); 
    });
    return result; 
}
```

I think it can check is user exist or not.
but it `result = true;` can't work, i guess it scopes  problem?
or ...? some else i need to research?

Comment: the mongo query function is async. The return statement will be executed before the query return results. So the result of the function will always be false.

Comment: so... result = true it's work 
but async let result = false faster than true?

Comment: how to solve this situation...
i don't want index.js have a lot database operation:((

Comment: sorry not sure about the correctness of the query. I was just pointing out the async nature of JS.